# Elasticsearch appends object fields on update instead of overwriting

Tags: elasticsearch

I have an object in Elasticsearch which may contain different fields. In my app this object is Enum so it can't actually contain more than one field at the same time. But when i do an update in Elasticsearch - it appends the fields instead of overwriting the whole object.

For example - the document may be public or accessible only to a group of users:

```json
POST _template/test_template
{
  "index_patterns": [
    "test*"
  ],
  "template": {
    "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1
    },
    "mappings": {
      "_source": {
        "enabled": true
      },
      "properties": {
        "id": {
          "type": "keyword"
        },
        "users": {
          "type": "object",
          "properties": {
            "permitted": {
              "type": "keyword"
            },
            "public": {
              "type": "boolean"
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
   "aliases" : {
      "test-alias" : { }
    }
}

POST test_doc/_doc/1
{
  "id": "1",
    "users": {
      "permitted": [
        "1", "2"
      ]
    }
}

POST _bulk
{"update":{"_index":"test_doc","_type":"_doc","_id":1}}
{"doc":{"id":"1","users":{"public": true}},"doc_as_upsert":true}

GET test-alias/_search
```

I am expecting this result:

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "users": {
        "public": true
    }
}
```

But the actual result is:

```json
{
    "id": "1",
    "users": {
        "permitted": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "public": true
    }
}
```

At the same time it overwrites the fields with the same name perfectly (i can change the permitted array or public field to false). How do you disable object fields appending?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to change the `action` in bulk request to `index` from `update`, correct request would be

```
{"index":{"_index":"71908768","_id":1}}
{"doc":{"id":"1","users":{"public": true}}}
```

refer actions and what they do in details in the [official Elasticsearch docs](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/docs-bulk.html#bulk-api-request-body). In short, `update` partially updates the document, while index action Indexes the specified document. **If the document exists, replaces the document and increments the version**.

Comment: `doc_as_upsert` is not needed in `index` as far as i know. I understand the difference, i don't quite understand why it is not overwriting specifically object fields. It seems to work fine on arrays and simple fields.

Comment: So to update (as in replace) one field in the existing document, I have to index the whole document? So update API is not really "update" but "append"?